# JMeter Proxy exclusion patterns still being recorded

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using JMeter to record traffic in my browser. In my URL Patterns to Exclude are:

`.*\.jpg`,
`.*\.js`,
`.*\.png`

Which looks like they should block these patterns (I've even tested it with a regex tester [here](http://rubular.com/r/P9ik6QhRtH))

Yet, I still see plenty of these files get pulled up. In a [related forum](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Proxy-exclude-pattern-doesn-t-work-td530175.html) someone had a similar issue, but his was caused by having additional url parameters afterwards (eg www.website.com/image.jpg?asdf=thisdoesntmatch). However this doesn't seem to be the case here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Even though you say it doesn't seem to be caused by trailing character, have you tried something like: `.*\.jpg.*` anyway?

Comment: Just gave that a try. It was a good idea, but It's still pulling those anyway =\

Comment: Worth a shot.  It sounds like it works to exclude some of the files it should, but not others.  Could you post some examples of what it successfully catches, and of those that it fails to?

Comment: How do I see which files are successfully excluded? I am able to see which ones are not being filtered, but I don't know how to see which ones are

Comment: You wanna hear something awesome? After the n-th time of trying it, it just works like it should now.

Comment: Glad it's working then.  Chalk it up to a bit of a case of the gremlins, I suppose.

Comment: Are the hits included by an 'include' pattern, which overrides the exclude?

Answer (score 14):

As already mentioned in the question comments it is probably a problem with the trailing characters. The pattern matcher is executed against the complete url including parameters.
So an URL `http://example.com/layout.css?id=123` is not matched against the pattern `.*\.css` 
The *JMeter HTTP Request Sample* seperates the *Path* and the *Parameters* so it might be not obvious when you look at the URL.

**Solution:**
Change the pattern to support trailing characters `.*\.css.*`

**Explained**
`.*` Any character
`\.` Matching the . (dot) character
`css` The character sequence css
`.*` Any character

Comment: Correct, all the CSS or JS that are recorded will have some parameters append to it. Otherwise those requests will not be recorded. Solution is as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the oposite: leave blank the URL Patterns to exclude and negate those patterns in the URL Patterns to Include box:

(?!.*.(bmp|css|js|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|swf|woff))(.*)